# How to include chromedriver in gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: python-3.x, cloud, gitlab-ci

I have a python selenium script that needs to be run in GitLab CI/CD. Script is running perfectly in local but the only issue is of chrome driver path in gitlab.
Do I also need to add the script to download the chrome?
I am new to gitlab CI/CD.Need help!!
Thanks

Comment: You headless mode to do selenium test using chrome. Refer this https://devqa.io/webdriver-headless-mode-chrome-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Create a Dockerfile which install all the browsers and their web drivers. Create that image and call that image in gitlab to run your tests. Here is the sample dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 python3-pip \
    fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libnspr4 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils libxss1 libdbus-glib-1-2 \
    curl unzip wget \
    xvfb


# install geckodriver and firefox

RUN GECKODRIVER_VERSION=`curl https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | grep -Po 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'` && \
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$GECKODRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver && \
    rm geckodriver-$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz

RUN FIREFOX_SETUP=firefox-setup.tar.bz2 && \
    apt-get purge firefox && \
    wget -O $FIREFOX_SETUP "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64" && \
    tar xjf $FIREFOX_SETUP -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox && \
    rm $FIREFOX_SETUP


# install chromedriver and google-chrome

RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/bin && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver && \
    rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

RUN CHROME_SETUP=google-chrome.deb && \
    wget -O $CHROME_SETUP "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" && \
    dpkg -i $CHROME_SETUP && \
    apt-get install -y -f && \
    rm $CHROME_SETUP


# install phantomjs

RUN wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
    tar -jxf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
    cp phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs && \
    rm phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2


RUN pip3 install selenium
RUN pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
RUN pip3 install Selenium-Screenshot

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /$APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME/

CMD tail -f /dev/null
CMD python3 example.py
```